# How to implement merge sort using recursion using ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, arraylist

Merge function seems to be not working, l1.size() == 0 gives me concurrent Modification Problem. How can I correct this function?

```
    public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2){
        if(l1.size()==0) {
            return l2;
        }
        else if(l2.size()==0)
            return l1;
        
        else {
            if(l1.get(0) < l2.get(0)) {
                int removed = l1.remove(0);
                List<Integer> l3 = merge(l1,l2);
                l3.add(0,removed);
                return l3;
            }
            else {
                int removed = l2.remove(0);
                List<Integer> l3 = merge(l1,l2);
                l3.add(0,removed);
                return l3;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi @EagerAssaultIxopi - you need to find some sample input and check that it does what you expect.  Also what happens if one of the List is not modifiable - `Collections.emptyList()` gives one for instance !!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an implementation of mergesort for a generic ArrayList

```
/**
     * perform a merge sort on the elements of data
     * 
     * 
     * @param data data != null, all elements of data are the same data type
     * @TimeComplexity: O(NlogN)
     */
    private void mergeSort(ArrayList<E> data) {
        if (data == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("paramater data cannot be null");
        }
        // creates new arrayList and initializes data.size() nulls
        ArrayList<E> temp = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            temp.add(null);
        }
        // sorts using recursion
        sort(data, temp, 0, data.size() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * helper method for merge sort
     * 
     * 
     * @TimeComplexity: O(NlogN)
     */
    private void sort(ArrayList<E> data, ArrayList<E> temp, int low, int high) {
        // if we can keep merging and sorting
        if (low < high) {
            int center = (low + high) / 2;
            // two recursion calls to split and merge the two splits
            sort(data, temp, low, center);
            sort(data, temp, center + 1, high);
            merge(data, temp, low, center + 1, high);
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper method for merge sort
     * 
     * 
     * @TimeComplexity: O(N)
     */
    private void merge(ArrayList<E> data, ArrayList<E> temp, int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd) {
        int leftEnd = rightPos - 1;
        int tempPos = leftPos;
        int numElements = rightEnd - leftPos + 1;
        // main loop
        while (leftPos <= leftEnd && rightPos <= rightEnd) {
            if (data.get(leftPos).compareTo(data.get(rightPos)) <= 0) {
                temp.set(tempPos, data.get(leftPos));
                leftPos++;
            } else {
                temp.set(tempPos, data.get(rightPos));
                rightPos++;
            }
            tempPos++;
        }
        // copy rest of left half
        while (leftPos <= leftEnd) {
            temp.set(tempPos, data.get(leftPos));
            tempPos++;
            leftPos++;
        }
        // copy rest of right half
        while (rightPos <= rightEnd) {
            temp.set(tempPos, data.get(rightPos));
            tempPos++;
            rightPos++;
        }
        // Copy temp back into data
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++, rightEnd--)
            data.set(rightEnd, temp.get(rightEnd));
    }
```